# IBM Bluemix IoT unsuccessfully sent

Tags: json, ibm-cloud, iot

When trying to complete the tutorial at https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/how-to-connect-mediatek-linkit-one-development-board-to-ibm-bluemix/

All runs fine except I am getting an "unsuccessfully sent" error.

I checked the status of the service all seems fine?

Not sure what to try next?

Edit:
Example of response when trying to connect to registered device.

---

temperature = 21.40
humidity = 47.10
Trying to connect to: d:ctk1yn:LinkitOneOffice:autumnlinkitone
Connected !!: 
publishing... !!: 
attempt to send {
"d": {
"myName": "LinkIt ONE",
"temperature (F)": 72,
"temperature (C)": 21,
"humidity": 47
}
}
to iot-2/evt/status/fmt/json
unsuccessfully sent

Comment: That tutorial walks through the quickstart connection and I notice the linked GitHub repository also has the code for connecting as a registered device. It looks like your error is with the registered connection.  Did the quickstart work ok for you?

Comment: I received the same unsuccessfully sent for both QuickStart and registered connection.

Comment: Earlier when I checked the logs it looked like your connection was ok, so perhaps there is a problem with the Json formatting.  I added the json tag to your question for other SMEs to see it.

Comment: Is there an example of the expected Json formatting?

Comment: this sample code creates JSON as well, but it does the temp differently. https://github.com/ibm-messaging/iot-arduino/blob/master/samples/registered/registered.ino  I think a good idea may be to comment on the recipe itself so the person who contributed that can say if it works.  I will comment there now.

Comment: Thank you I'll swap it out to generate what's in the new sample code and see if it helps.

Comment: The other thing I notice in the log is that the server is disconnecting you around 95 seconds each time so it may be that your delay is too long before sending data.

Comment: I found the solution I took the line breaks data+="\n"; out of the json being generated. Worked for both quickstart and registered scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure json being generated is a single line string with no line breaks.